# Second order action inflationary cosmology

Tags: action, cosmological-inflation

I'm studying the cosmological perturbation features in the inflationary model from a paper in which inflaton perturbations and metric tensor perturbation are treated at the same time. To do this, it considers an expansion of the action of the coupled system (gravity+inflaton) up to second order in the linear perturbations, which is written:

*S($\phi=\bar{\phi}+\delta \phi$, g$_{\mu\nu}$=$\bar{g}$$_{\mu\nu}$+$\delta$g$_{\mu\nu}$)=S$^{(0)}$($\bar{\phi}$, $\bar{g}$$_{\mu\nu}$)+S$^{(1)}$($\bar{\phi}$, $\bar{g}$$_{\mu\nu}$; $\delta \phi$, $\delta$g$_{\mu\nu}$)+S$^{(2)}$($\bar{\phi}$, $\bar{g}$$_{\mu\nu}$; $\delta \phi$, $\delta$g$_{\mu\nu}$)*

where the bar over the variable means that the variable belongs to the homogeneous universe. The zero order term contains only the homogeneous part, the first-order term contains all terms linear in the perturbations and the second-order one contains the term quadratic in the linear perturbations.

In the paper, it's said that the first order term vanishes when one substitutes the FLRW equations of motion in it and integrates by parts. Could anyone explain this to me with more detail?

I link here the paper I referred to before (page 37):
https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0405053

Comment: I think that your problem is already solved by the author after your citation "[...] which is
not very surprising since this is how one gets the homogeneous equations of
motion, via the Euler-Lagrange equations, from the variation of the action."